# VBA to extract in excel from a word informations

Tags: excel, vba

I have a swift message saved in word and i want to extract in excel some certain informations from the swift message

For example part of the swift message:

```
97A - Safekeeping Account:
Qualifier : SAFE
Account Number: 223323
17B - Flag:
Qualifier: ACTI
Flag : Y
17B - Flag:
Qualifier: CONS
Flag : N
16S - End Block GENL:
GENL
16R - Start Block SUBSAFE(Sequence B Sub-safekeeping Account):
SUBSAFE
16R - Start Block FIN(Sequence B1 Financial Instrument):
FIN
35B - Ident. of the Financial Instr.:
Identification of Security: ISIN HHHGDJKKKK
Description of Security : bjjsdhaskhd
REGISTERED SHARES
93B - Balance:
Qualifier : AGGR
Quantity Type Code: UNIT
Balance : 8300, (8.300,00)
16R - Start Block SUBBAL(Subsequence B1b Sub-Balance):
SUBBAL
```

I want to extract in excel in 3 columns:

```
97A_Account Number  35B_ Identification of Security 93B_Balance
223323               ISIN HHHGDJKKKK                    8.300,00
```

And then to loop into the word file for the next `97A Account Number, 35B IDenfication of Security and 93B Balance` until the end of the document

Can you help with a VBA for this?

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow. Could you post what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I have tried in excel with formulas to extract from a single column the informations but it steel doesn't look like the final result that i want to have so that's why i have asked for help

Comment: That is why I was suggesting you paste your VBA code. Because your question contains insufficient elements. You have to give us all the lements to reproduce your problem.